How do I define a C/C++ preprocessor variable in Meson?
I want to conditionally define a variable that I then can use within C/C++ sources to conditionally compile some code, like this:
#ifdef MY_MESON_VARIABLE
    // some code
#endif

How do I go about actually setting MY_MESON_VARIABLE from Meson build system code such that it becomes accessible to the C preprocessor? I already know how do flow control in Meson, so I just need to know how to set a preprocessor variable.

Passing -DMU_MESON_VARIABLE (or /DMU_MESON_VARIABLE for visual) to the command line, your build system might have dedicated api to add those definitions.

https://mesonbuild.com/Adding-arguments.html

@Jarod42 thanks, I guess it was hiding from me in plain sight.

How to add preprocessor defines to a target?

Meson allows you to define preprocessor variables via compilation arguments. To do this, use add_project_arguments or add_global_arguments, add to Meson.build:
add_project_arguments('-DMY_MESON_VARIABLE', language: 'c')

The -D before the variable name tells the compiler to define the specified variable.
The add_project_arguments function adds compilation arguments that will be applied to the entire project.
This will make MY_MESON_VARIABLE available for #ifdef in C/C++ sources.
